# Experiment: More aggressive review queue indicator

Tags: discussion

Over on Meta Stack Exchange, I announced [an experiment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304445/1438) that would:

- Turn on the review queue indicator whenever there's a task available in any queue.
- All queues with at least one task will be marked with a red dot. There are no grey dots:

  [image: Inbox Zero indicator]

**This *will* mean you'll be notified of outstanding tasks you can't clear.** We are aware of a problem that people will be notified of queues that they don't have the privilege to access. That's next on the list to fix. The goal is to be more aggressive with the indicator to see if we can clear tasks more quickly. Please let us know if we've gone too far.

And in general, we're interested in any feedback to this change: positive, negative or noncommittal.

Comment: I'm sure what problem this is trying to fix. Clarification please.

Comment: @a4android: Sure thing. The [default logic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly) assumes that people only want to be notified if there's a backlog in one of the queues. That's a safe assumption on some sites that have permanent backlogs, but not so good on a site like this which often has no outstanding tasks in any of the queues. In that case, people probably want to be notified right away in order to provide prompt feedback.

Comment: I do like this idea. I could just be me seeing things, but it feels like the queues are getting cleared out quicker. Will we be able to see statistics about the average time a post spends in review, to see if there's a significant improvement in processing efficiency?

Comment: @HDE226868: Yes, that's one of the things I'll be looking at. (Haven't written the query just yet, however.)

Answer (score 7):

I'm totally in favour of this.

I hardly ever review since the nav bar changes as there is no notification unless you open the menu and I completely forget about reviewing..

If there was a dot there whenever there was reviewing to be done I'd be far more likely to remember to check it and do some reviewing when I have time.

Comment: I'm with Adalia.  The dot helped me notice the need tremendously.

Answer (score 4):

My problem is that I'm not getting the main queue notification.

Firefox 57.0.2 (64-bit)
Windows 8 (It's a work machine, don't blame me!)

[image]

Comment: I would suggest reposting this as a separate [bug] [top-bar] [review] (or similar tags) question and deleting it as an answer here, to keep this Q&A focused solely on Worldbuilding participating in this UX experiment.

Comment: This is a cross-site issue, independent of this experiment, so I suggest posting it on mSE.